# Sort calculated field in Angular

Tags: angularjs

Is there a way to sort a calculated field in angular? how would I sort the values in the calculated column of totalTime ?

item in items:orderBy['field1']

```
{{item.field1}}
{{totalTime(item.date1,item.date2)}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a a filter that calculates the totalTime and add it as a property to your item before applying your orderBy filter. See this [working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qsLvsLj3/1/).

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items | getTotalTime | orderBy:['totalTime']">
    {{item.field1}}
    {{item.totalTime}}
</div>
```

The filter

```
app.filter('getTotalTime', function() {
    return function(items) {
        for(var i=0; i<items.length; i++) {
         var item = items[i];
         item.totalTime = item.date1 + item.date2;

        }
        return items;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

From https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy

> A predicate to be used by the comparator to determine the order of elements.
>
> Can be one of:
>
> function: Getter function. The result of this function will be sorted using the <, ===, > operator.
>
> string: ...

```
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="MainController as main">
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="i in main.items | orderBy:main.inverse:true">{{ i }}</li>
  </ul>
</body>


function MainController() {
    var vm = this;
    vm.items = [ 3, 2, 1];
    vm.inverse = function (i) {
      return 1/i;
    }
}
```